# ASP.net webapplication hangs for any request

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, crystal-reports

All,

We have ASP.net application hosted in IIS7.0. It was running smoothly for more than 2 yrs. Currently we are facing the following issue.
Whenever the user perform activity the appliaction hangs up and did not give any response. These activity involves report generation using crystal report tool. We analysed the DB also there were no call to DB. We restarted the application pool and it is working fine. But frequently we are facing this issue. Please provide any solution.

Language : VB.Net
Framework : .Net 2.0
Appliaction : ASP.Net
Component : Crystal report 10

Comment: infinite timeout on connection ?

Comment: infinite timeout on http response not on DB connection. There is no DB call.